# CSS not rendered correctly on page load/reload

Tags: html, css, frontend, rendering

I'm trying to apply my CSS-file to my webpage.
When I load my website, I shortly see the site rendered correctly (with my CSS-styles applied), while the page is still loaded. When the page finished loading some of the styles I defined with CSS dissappear, for example the background-color or the alignment of some texts. Sometimes when I reload the page the site is rendered normally without me changing the browser or the code. I allready tried deleting the browser cache but nothing changed. I use Google Chrome. I can see that the CSS-file must be loaded correctly, as some of the styles are applied, and the page reneders correctly while the loading processes.

This is an image of my site while loading:
[image: website while loading:]

This is an image of my site after loading:
[image: website after loading]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the styles all loading from the same style sheet or do you have multiple stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some other css or js file is loaded after your css file. please provide a link to your page or post the html.

If you use the development tools (F12) you could interspect the Network tab. here you can see whitch files are loaded and in witch order they are

Comment: Thank you that was the solution. I found a css-reference i totally forgot about in my code